# How can i make bootstrap thumbnail all same height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Heeyy, i am making my website with bootstrap.. but i have some column problems. i want to have columns with text, but when the page get smaller, they start pushing each other down and way. How can i fix that?

My website is: http://www.dev-bunker.nl

The problem is on the "home" page. but also on the "diensten" page and on the "wie zijn wij" page.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h2 class="title">
                    Onze werkwijze
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://dev-bunker.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/bedenken.png">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h2>Bedenken</h2>
                            <p>
                                Het bedenken is het eerste onderdeel van het proces. Tijdens dit onderdeel gaan we met de klant, maar ook met het team, nadenken over het de huisstijl, indeling, de inhoud en alles wat er om heen draait.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://dev-bunker.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/design-icon.png">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h2>Ontwerpen</h2>
                            <p>
                                Tijdens de ontwerp fase maken we wireframes en volledige ontwerpen, samen met de klant bespreken we de ontwerpen. Wanneer de klant deze heeft goed gekeurt gaat de realisatie fase beginnen.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://dev-bunker.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/realisatie.png">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h2>Realiseren</h2>
                            <p>
                                Met de realisatie fase gaan we met het team aan de website of applicatie werken. Deze proberen wij gelijk te maken aan het ontwerp, zodat de klant precies weet wat hem / haar te wachten staat.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://dev-bunker.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/check.png">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h2>Uittesten &&nbsp;nazorg</h2>
                            <p>
                                Als de website of applicatie klaar is, krijgt de klant hem te zien. Als er dingen niet kloppen of er werken stukken van de website / applicatie niet. Gaan wij verder tot alles werkent is.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div> <!-- end container -->
```

Comment: Edited: Really what is blocking those elements from sliding to left and under is the first `div` height is longer than the next. I believe  with bootstrap you can force those `div`'s to the same height.

Comment: Yes but how.. haha i have searched the internet but cant find anything.. people have used php and javascript and jquery.. but i dont know how to use it in my code.

Comment: try adding a forced height to your `.thumbnail` class i.e `height:450px` should work for you. You can always create another class for this and place it on the HTML elements in question. This is just one solution, Bootstrap should handle all this. I'll continue to look into it if the above suggestion doesn't work at all.

Comment: Ok i will try that. but is there no option in  bootrap to make a thumbnails the same size. so when 1 thumbnail have 100 words. and 1 thumbnail have 10 words that they are al the same size. even though if you make one 1000 words that they all grow to the same size. if you know what i mean

Comment: Found a fix, check answer below. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats the default behavior of bootstrap. If the content gets too big for the screen size, if will push down the columns on mobile devices.

it works like this:

the classes col-lg-3, col-md-3 and col-sm-6 override how the class "row" places the columns.

the col-lg-3 mean it will use 3/12 of the screen size on large sizes
the col-md-3 mean it will use 3/12 of the screen size on normal sizes
the col-sm-6 mean it will use 6/12 of the screen size on smal sizes

if you want the columns to be 4 colums on any device, you should add col-xs-3 to all those divs.

it will be like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
```

the col-xs-3 class tells bootstrap to use 4 colums on mobile devices as well

**UPDATE**

Add a class to each one of those divs and set a minimum height on it.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 myTestClass">
```

CSS

```
.myTestClass: min-height: 550px;
```

try changing the min height value to fit exactly the height you need on each page

Comment: Yes i know.. but i have a row.. with 9 columns with the size: col-md-4. but when 1 col is heigher then the other columns, he will push all the columns to the side. leaving a gab in the colums

Comment: Ahh, now I understand the problem. It didnt occur to me on the home page, but it did on the diensten page.

the solution is easy, add a class to each one of those divs with a minimun height. I'll update my Answer

Comment: Yes on the home page you can only see it when you make screen to md/sm size

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Ok thanks. i will try llldapt his answer first and i that does not work i will try yours.. thanks! I will give you update is it worked!

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't being able to put all thumbnails (with captions) in the same row. They were showing up and down based on the height of the thumbnail above. `min-height` worked great for me to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use Bootstrap 4, they added in `.row-eq-height` allowing you to do exactly as you want.

Simply replace the Bootstrap 3 `<link>` and replace with a [Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/) CDN

Then add `row-eq-height` to the row with all the `<div>`'s and your'e set. I tested in console and all looks good. Hope it works for you.

[image]

Comment: Does that also work with making the thumbnails the same size?

Comment: Updated with picture, what you're looking for?

Comment: ow that is what i want. can yuo show me how you did that in the code?

Comment: It is weird.. on the wie zijn wij page..(where you are now) it is good. but on the diensten page it is not good..

Comment: If you already reference Bootstrap 4, `<div class="row">` that holds all your `.thumbnail`'s now needs to be `<div class="row row-eq-height">` and that is it.

Comment: On the home, are you still referencing Bootstrap 3? You will need to change for all pages.

Comment: i have added it, but still no luck
https://gyazo.com/88d035eed7aa7a2380a9a4d337681e62

Comment: Right on, those would be my guesses, set a height or use Bootstrap 4 and `row-eq-height` class. Is the Diensten page the only one? At that point it could be the HTML Markup, something in there.

Comment: It is on the diensten page. Home page and the wie zijn wij page.. on all the pages with thumbnails

Comment: At this point, at least until/if you find another option, use the above along with `.thumbnail {
  min-height: 350px;
}` Or really any height that will cover the BIGGEST thumbnail container.

Comment: Also note, padding/margin added to `.thumbnail` containers could be playing a part in the strange behavior. Try resetting the padding and margin to 0 for those classes.

Comment: Yeah that could be. But ik have not changed the margin.. only the padding but that sound not chang anything. But i will try to make it fixed height and use @medias to chang the hightech for mobile and tablet